# Transition frame in an animation

Tags: java, animation, 2d, libgdx

Ok this is going to be something stupidly easy but for some reason im just not catching it.

I have a standing animation, and a moving animation what i want is to play a single frame transition inbetween the two animations, i cant seem to accomplish it (tried it with booleans)

Here is my code perhaps someone can help.

Also, i do seperate animations for facing left/right, is there a way i can just flip the single animation?

Thanks in advance from a noob coder -- Heres my code with some irrelivent stuff cut out

```
public class Player extends Sprite implements InputProcessor {

private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
private float speed = 60 * 2, gravity = 60 * 2.2f, animationTime = 0;

private boolean canJump;
private boolean attacking;
private boolean starting = true;


private Animation still, left, right, attack, start;
private TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer;



public Player(Animation still, Animation left, Animation right, Animation attack, Animation start, TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer) {
    super(still.getKeyFrame(0));
    this.still = still;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.start = start;
    this.collisionLayer = collisionLayer;
    setSize(getWidth(), getHeight() /* * 1.5f*/);
    //setScale((float) 1.4);
}

@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
    update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    super.draw(spriteBatch);



    // update animation
    animationTime += delta;

         setRegion(

            velocity.x < 0 ? left.getKeyFrame(animationTime) :


            velocity.x > 0  ? right.getKeyFrame(animationTime) :

            attacking == true ? attack.getKeyFrame(animationTime) :
            still.getKeyFrame(animationTime));



}


@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    switch(keycode) {
    case Keys.W:
        if(canJump) {
            velocity.y = speed / 1.8f;
            canJump = false;
        }
        break;
    case Keys.A:
        velocity.x = -speed;
        animationTime = 0;
        break;
    case Keys.D:
        velocity.x = speed;
        animationTime = 0;





case Keys.I:
    attacking = true;
    animationTime = 0.15f;
}
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    switch(keycode) {
    case Keys.A:
    case Keys.D:
        velocity.x = 0;
        animationTime = 0;

    case Keys.I:
        animationTime = 0;
        attacking = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And from my screen to get it on the map

```
@Override
public void show() {
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map.tmx");



    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    backimage = new Sprite(new Texture("images/backgrounds/background.png"));

    playerAtlas = new TextureAtlas("img/player/player.pack");
    Animation still, left, right, attack, start;
    still = new Animation(2 / 2f, playerAtlas.findRegions("still"));
    left = new Animation(1 / 6f, playerAtlas.findRegions("left"));
    right = new Animation(2 / 26f, playerAtlas.findRegions("right"));
    attack = new Animation(1 / 6f, playerAtlas.findRegions("attack"));
    start = new Animation(1 / 2f, playerAtlas.findRegions("start"));
    still.setPlayMode(Animation.LOOP);
    left.setPlayMode(Animation.LOOP);
    right.setPlayMode(Animation.LOOP);
    start.setPlayMode(Animation.NORMAL);
    attack.setPlayMode(Animation.NORMAL);

    player = new Player(still, left, right, attack, start, (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0));

    MapLayer layer = map.getLayers().get("objects");
        for(MapObject object : layer.getObjects())
            if(object.getName().equals("playerstart"))
             player.setPosition(object.getProperties().get("x", Integer.class),  object.getProperties().get("y", Integer.class));


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(player);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is handling what animation will be rendered using states:

```
public static final int STATE_IDLE = 0;
public static final int STATE_WALKINGLEFT = 1;
public static final int STATE_WALKINGRIGHT = 2;
public static final int STATE_TRANSITIONLEFT = 3;
public static final int STATE_TRANSITIONRIGHT = 4;

public int state = STATE_IDLE;
```

Then change the state to transition with the input:

```
case Keys.A:
    state = STATE_TRANSITIONLEFT;
    velocity.x = -speed;
    animationTime = 0;
    break;
case Keys.D:
    state = STATE_TRANSITIONRIGHT;
    velocity.x = speed;
    animationTime = 0;
```

In your render method, wait for some time and change the transition state to the walking state:

```
if(animationTime>0.1F){ //your transition frame time
    if(state == STATE_TRANSITIONLEFT){
        state = STATE_WALKINGLEFT;
        animationTime = 0;
    }
    if(state == STATE_TRANSITIONRIGHT){
        state = STATE_WALKINGRIGHT;
        animationTime = 0;
    }
}
```

Return the state to idle if input:

```
case Keys.A:
case Keys.D:
    velocity.x = 0;
    state == STATE_IDLE;
    animationTime = 0;
```

And finally, render the current animation:

```
switch(state){
    case STATE_IDLE:
        //draw idle animation
        break;
    case STATE_TRANSITIONLEFT:
        //draw transitionleft frame
        break;
    case STATE_WALKINGLEFT:
        //draw walkingleft animation
        break;
    //etc...
}
```

And for your last question. Yep, you can flip the regions of your animation:

[TextureRegion#flip](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#flip%28boolean,%20boolean%29)